# How to do Client Authentication using installed .pfx certificate in Swift URLSession?

Tags: swift, authentication, client, urlsession, pfx

To begin with, I would like to describe my requirement first. I have developed an iPadOS app, and I want only those devices will be able to use this app in which a specific certificate (.pfx) is already installed.
I went through a lot of articles, however, they show to bundle the certificate in the project bundle. Which means, any device install this app can use it successfully as the certificate is already included.
Is there any solution for this? I have shared the URLSession code here below.

```
import Foundation

class NetworkingManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = NetworkingManager()
    let cert = PKCS12.init(mainBundleResource: "yilm*******kost.de", resourceType: "pfx", password: "************")

    private override init() {}

    func request<T: Codable>(_ endpoint: Endpoint, type: T.Type) async throws -> T {
        guard let url = endpoint.url else {
            throw NetworkingError.invalidUrl
        }
    
        print(url)
        let request = buildRequest(url, method: endpoint.methodType)
    
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)
    
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
          (200...300) ~= response.statusCode else {
            let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
            throw NetworkingError.invalidStatusCode(code: statusCode!)
        }
    
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let res = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        return res
    }
}

private extension NetworkingManager {
    private func buildRequest(_ url: URL, method: Endpoint.MethodType) -> URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
        switch method {
        case .GET:
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
        case .POST(let submissionData):
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = submissionData
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    }
    
    request.addValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
    if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Token") {
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
    return request
}


extension NetworkingManager: URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, cert.urlCredential())
        }
        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        }
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, .none)
    }
}
```

By the way, this code works for any device. Because, I have bundled the certificate in the project bundle and provided certificate name and password manually.

Any help would be appreciated..